# Como resolver a falha SLF4J no maven?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

**Problema com Maven install:**

---

Quando rodo no eclipse `Run As > Maven install` sempre recebo essa mensagem:

---

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building ProjetoTeste 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
```

---

Porque ocorre `SLF4J: Failed` e como resolver?

---

**Observação:** Utilizo Maven pelo Eclipse e com Java.

Comment: No arquivo `pom.xml` não adicionei essas bibliotecas, toda a configuração de build path estou realizando através dele. Estou correto em dizer que ele seria o build path do mavem? Pergunto isso por que no `eclipse` tem um lugar chamado build path (onde configuro jars em um projeto do eclipse).

Comment: Para quem ainda está com o problema. Apague a pasta onde o maven salva as dependências e baixa de novo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quando você falou sobre Eclipse, logo pensei se tratar de um *bug* do plugin **m2e** (*Maven to Eclipse*), que é o plugin do Eclipse para integração com o Maven sem necessidade de linha de comando. Dito e feito!

**Este não é um problema com seu projeto!**

Fiz um teste com meu Eclipse e inicialmente não consegui reproduzir o problema. Então encontrei [este tópico no SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11916706/slf4j-failed-to-load-class-org-slf4j-impl-staticloggerbinder-error) e a questão parece ser com a instalação embutido da Maven que já vem com o plugin. Ao trocar para uma instalação externa o problema desaparece.

Eu removi minha instalação externa do Maven para reproduzir as mensagens. Na imagem abaixo, capturada há alguns instantes, mostro o erro abaixo e a configuração para adicionar uma instalação externa mais acima:

[image: Adicionando uma nova instalação]

Após adicionar a outra instalação, o problema não ocorre mais.

[image: maven externo]

Resultado:

[image: Resultado após maven externo]

Comment: Muito obrigado problema resolvido, ajudou bastante e se entendi bem o eclipse vem com uma configuração padrão da instalação do `maven`! Só é necessário informar onde está a pasta do `maven`. @utluiz tenho uma dúvida sobre o `setting.xml` devo criar outro tópico ou pergunto aqui mesmo?

Comment: @EduardoBentoRochaJunior Acho que seria melhor criar outro.

Answer (score 1):

Outra solução rápida (e suja) para o bug do "SLF4J" (caso se deseje manter a versão embutida do Maven):

Copiar os arquivos: "slf4j-api-[*qualquer-versao*].jar" e "slf4j-simple-[*qualquer-versao*].jar", para dentro da pastinha $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/ext

Onde: $JAVA_HOME é o caminho onde instalou seu Java.

**Obs.:** Ambos os ".jar" podem ser encontrados dentro do pacote para download disponível em: https://www.slf4j.org/download.html

Esta foi a solução que adotei.

Answer (score 0):

Tive problemas com exemplos.
O tomcat não funcionava na versao 1.5.9.RELEASE:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> 
</parent>
```

Erro
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.

Solução foi mudar a versão para 1.5.0.RELEASE e funcionou perfeito.

Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
Started Demo01Application in 4.829 seconds (JVM running for 5.402)
Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 28 ms